# Intercepting Ctrl + F4 keystrokes in a Flex application running in IE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internet-explorer, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Some of my Flash application components require to intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard events.
Unfortunately, the `KeyboardEvent` is not caught when running the app under IE since it is conflicting with the IE native shortcut (closing the active tab).

Is there a way (ideally relying on Flash principles) to intercept such keystrokes?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to capture `keyboardEvents` with the <kbd>F4</kbd> keycode because the <kbd>F4</kbd> keydown in IE shoot focus into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the flash apps needs focus, inside an input control to accept keystrokes and fire off Keyboard events.  Is that the case?

I know in Firefox, if a Flash App has focus I can't do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab.  It is entirely possible that IE specific keystrokes always bubble up to the browser.

Comment: Yes. In my case, the Flash app has the focus.